# How to modify values in a raster that are smaller OR larger than two thresholds

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator, conditional

In ArcGIS 10.1 (advanced license), I have a raster dataset representing the wind speed (in knots). I want to be able to set the wind speed value to a specific value (say, for the sake of argument, a very low value like 0.1) only for those cells with a value smaller than (say) 3 and larger than 10. My best guess is to use a Conditional statement in RASTER CALCULATOR, but I am not familiar with that.
I have tried something like:
    *Con(("raster" <  3) | ("raster"  >  10), 0.1, "raster")* 
but it seems to not work.
Is that syntax right, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use raster calculator this can all be done within the [CON](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/con-.htm) tool. An example below shows the processing of elevation data to turn any values above 10m and below 0m to 0.1 whilst keeping all other original values as they are.

[image: Using the CON tool]